# Scheduled AWS Lambda function doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to schedule the lambda poll data from Redshift every minute

so I configure the lambda function with:

```
event source type: CloudWatch Events - Schedule
schedule expression: rate(1 minute)
Enable event source: yes
```

but the lambda function isn't triggered at all, it gives the right result every time I start it by pushing the "test" button.

Comment: How are you testing whether the lambda was invoked?  Does it show up in CloudWatch logs?  Note the lambda must have a role policy allowing `cloudwatch:` actions.

Comment: @ataylor I let lambda send a message to SNS which then fire an email to me

Answer (score 0):

answer by myself, after having created the event source it has to be enabled explicitly.